# jquery div doesn't show when toggle is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I seem to be having a weird problem with the responsive CSS and the JQuery

1. When the window is resized to 600px
2. The hr(icon) is clicked to show Nav
3. Once hr is clicked again to hide the nav, and the window is resized, the nav isn't visible

if nav is visible and then resized > 600px nav stays visible throughout.

Is the problem something to do with the jquery code?

**CODE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/ag3tdeqe/**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftmenu">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://callmenick.com/theme/callmenick/img/logo.svg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="icon">
            <hr/>
            <hr/>
            <hr/>
        </div>
        <div class="social"> 
            <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-instagram"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-youtube"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-vine"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-tumblr"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-linkedin"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li> <a class="scroll" href="#home">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a class="scroll" href="#videos">Videos</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a class="scroll" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a class="scroll" href="#about">About</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a class="scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    margin-left: 250px;
    height: 100%;
}
.leftmenu {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    background-color: #28aadc;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-transition: .3s;
    transition: transform .3s;
}
.leftmenu .nav {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.leftmenu .nav ul {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.leftmenu .nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
.leftmenu .nav ul li > a {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width:80%;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#00648c;
    font-family:'arkhip';
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:5px;
}
.leftmenu .nav ul li > a:hover {
    color:white;
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
    .container {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .leftmenu {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        float:none;
        position:relative;
        height:80px;
    }
    .leftmenu > h1 {
        font-size: 80%;
    }
    .leftmenu .nav {
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        padding:0px;
        margin-top: -35px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .leftmenu .logo {
        margin:0 auto;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        float:left;
    }
    .leftmenu .nav ul li {
        width:100px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .leftmenu .nav ul li > a {
        width:20px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .leftmenu {
        max-height: 80px;
        overflow: visible;
        margin-top: -10px;
    }
    .icon {
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        float: right;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .icon hr {
        width:40px;
        border:2px solid white;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .icon hr:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .icon:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .leftmenu .nav {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        right:0px;
        float:none;
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 95%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        top:80px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #28aadc;
        border-left: 1px solid #28aadc;
        border-right: 1px solid #28aadc
    }
    .leftmenu .nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    .leftmenu .nav ul li:hover a {
        color:black;
    }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".icon").click(function() {
    $(".leftmenu .nav").toggle(); 
});

$(".leftmenu .nav ul li > a").click(function() {
    $(".icon:visible").click();
});
```

Comment: Why such a long selector? Just use `$('.scroll')`

Comment: Oh thanks @BenMansley

Comment: @freedomn-m - What would be the best way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @GSoni It looks like its behaving as it should, maybe its not behaving as you expected it to. This is a responsive dropdown menu as freedomn-2 has explained. Here's what I observe:  when the menu is open, I can access the links no matter how wide the page is. Is that the same for you?

Comment: @zer00ne - The issue i am having is when the page is < 600px the icon shows and when it is clicked and then clicked to hide the nav and the page is then resized - the nav doesnt appear

Comment: Ah, I gotcha, ok I'll take a look

Comment: You might like to edit your question with the specific reproduction steps: 1 small window, 2 click to show menu, 3 click to hide menu, 4 resize to wide menu doesn't show.

Comment: @freedomn-m - Edited! Thanks!

Comment: You could have got around this by adding a class rather than changing the style - then the class can be `display:none` when smaller but still `display:block` in the wider css section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
$(".leftmenu .nav").toggle();
```

adds

```
display: none
```

to your menu after the second click on the icon to hide it.

Use the following to remove it:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".leftmenu .nav").css("display", "");
});
```

Comment: That fixes the problem! Thanks a lot! Quick question, what is the difference between doing **.css("display", "none") and .css("display", "")**

Comment: An empty css value in jquery removes all dynamically added style to the element, reverting the value to the one on the stylesheet or otherwise to the default (block in this case)

Comment: One more thing, I highly recommend you to use developer tools (if you haven't) to locate the underlying issues next time you encounter this kind of tricky problems. Press F12 on Firefox/Chrome/IE to open it up. I personally use Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

To trigger an event handler remotely, you use `trigger()`.

`$('.icon:visible').trigger('click');`

Comment: I don't understand what this is doing?

Comment: Calling .click() doesn't trigger the event handler which toggles it. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/trigger/